# How to add SideMenu without POD and Carthage?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, side-menu

I want to add this [Side Menu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) without using POD or Carthage, How can i do this.

Comment: what does the **Carthage** meant here??

Comment: @agent_stack Carthage is a ruthlessly simple tool to manage dependencies in Swift. For more reading https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/getting-started-with-carthage-to-manage-dependencies-in-swift-and-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing a git clone and then copying the files from `SideMenu/Pods/Classes` in your project should be enough.

I checked the dependencies of the project and there are none. This means that cocoapods won't get you more projects so you should be safe.

Comment: please delete your answer I want to delete my question

Answer (score 0):

You can always add libraries by manually adding the files required by the library . Here you can get the files inside the Pod/Classes. There are four files drag and drop them in your project , and import .h file in your bridging header. You will be able to import library in your files. Hope This helps you out .[image]

Comment: please delete your answer I want to delete my question